# Automatic rewards payout: which one handles the overdelegation?

Tags: baking

I checked [Tezos Reward Distributor](https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-reward-distributor) and [Backerei](https://github.com/cryptiumlabs/backerei/) and both seem to not handle the overdelegation possibility.

Are there other projects that handle automatic payouts, and also overdelegation (which means, do not send rewards to whom might have delegated too late or too much)?